# How can find and remove "Unknown" from a filename only for .csv and .pdf files

Tags: bash, rename

Ubuntu 18.04. I have a top folder with thousands of folders and files below, many levels deep. A lot of files have "Unknown" in the title that I would like removed without having to do it manually.

StJamesRow.2010.Unknown.pdf > StJamesRow.2010.pdf

StJamesRow.2010.Unknown.csv > StJamesRow.2010.csv

MarbleArch.2015.Unknown.pdf > MarbleArch.2015.pdf

MarbleArch.2015.Unknown.csv > MarbleArch.2015.csv

I would like to run a command at the top level and have it recurse down. It should not remove "Unknown" from a folder name if it finds unknown in the folder title. It should only be removed for csv and pdf files. Would be great if I could dry-run it first with a log of changes before going headfirst into it.

Thanks for reading

Comment: Try using `find . -name "*Unknown*" -type f` it should give you list of files having `Unknown` in filename. Then pipe the output to awk to rename the file.

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The shell can do some cool string processing, like chopping off substrings at either end of a string:

```
find . -name '*Unknown.pdf' |
while read file; do
    mv "$file" "${file%.Unknown.pdf}.pdf"
done
```

For a dry run, make it `echo mv ...`.

Read all about these %, %%, #, and ## chop functions in your shell manual's section on *parameter expansion*.

Comment: Maybe need to add csv support, like `find . -type f -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*\.Unknown\.(csv|pdf)$"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one liner:

```
find . -type f -name "*Unknown*" | rename 's/(.*).Unknown(.*)(csv|pdf)/$1$2$3/'
```

which can remove '.Unknown' from any position but first and last,
or this one:

```
find . -type f -name "*Unknown*" | rename 's/(.*)Unknown.(csv|pdf)/$1$2/'
```

if '.Unknown' should be removed from the position just before the extension pdf or csv

**EDIT:**

If you need dry-run version, you can use `sed` and stdout instead of `rename`:

```
find . -type f -name "*Unknown*" | sed 's/\(.*\)Unknown.\(csv\|pdf\)/\1Unknown.\2 -> \1\2/'
```

which gives the output:

```
./StJamesRow.2010.Unknown.csv -> ./StJamesRow.2010.csv
./MarbleArch.2015.Unknown.pdf -> ./MarbleArch.2015.pdf
```